# Connect android phone to UWP application offline

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-8.1

I am building a C# UWP Windows 8.1 application. I will like to know if there is a way I can connect my phone to my UWP Desktop app offline. I intended to transfer certain data and eliminate the time it takes for the devices to communicate with the server (- especially in cases of bad/no network here in Nigeria).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the two devices either using Bluetooth or Wi-fi direct. Bluetooth will probably be easier to setup. The process will be different for both platforms:

- Bluetooth - [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth), [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth)
- Wi-Fi Direct - [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect), [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct)

Bluetooth has broader support, but Wi-Fi direct may prove faster if you want "near real-time" performance.

Comment: Thanks,  @Martin Zikmund

Can this also allow me to send data to my controllers (API)?

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider marking it as solution so that the question is resolved.